# Properly bit packing for enum and typedef struct

Tags: c++, bit, bit-packing, nibble

I am trying to do some bit packing to transmit data in the small format possible, but I am unsure how to archive it, I started with a typedef struct where I gave the size to each element, but when I am trying to transmit it using UART, in the other end I receive it as one byte for each element

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
    enum type 
    {
        id_hardware=1,
        id_software,
        id_led,
        id_adc,
        id_motor,
        id_battery
                /* ... some enums more */
                id_some = 31
    };
    #pragma pack(push, 1)
    typedef struct
    {
        uint8_t id_software     : 8;
        uint8_t id_led_light    : 8;    /* values from 0 to 100 -> 0 - 100% */ 
        uint8_t id_adc          : 8;    /* e.g 45,xx */
        uint8_t id_adc_precision: 4;    /* e.g xx,06 */
        uint8_t battery_voltage : 6;    
        uint8_t hardware_id     : 5;
        uint8_t id_motor        : 1;    /* on-off */
    } data;
    #pragma pack(pop)
    data obj_data;

int main()
{
    obj_data.hardware_id        = 1;
    obj_data.id_software        = 1;
    obj_data.id_led_light       = 50;
    obj_data.id_adc             = 40;
    obj_data.id_adc_precision   = 27;
    obj_data.battery_voltage    = 50;
    obj_data.id_motor           = 0;

    printf("[%x][%x][%x][%x]",id_hardware , obj_data.hardware_id, id_battery, obj_data.battery_voltage);
```

for the code above I am sending the data as:

hex: [1][1][6][32]

binary: 00000001 00000001 00000110 00100000

where my real intention is receiving something like this:

[8][4C][40]

binary: ***00001*** 00001 ***00110*** 0 0100000 ***0***

Comment: (unrelated to title) Sorry.  This does not appear c++-ish to me.  Example: C uses <stdio.h>, but C++ would use <cstdio> ... these are different.  C++ std::printf is from <cstdio>.  But why did you include <iostream>?

Comment: Don't use `structs` as network protocols.

Comment: I think you forgot to include <cstdint>, for uint8_t.

Comment: Consider enabling more warnings:  Example:  warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]  (for the assignment of value 27 to 4 bit field obj_data.id_adc_precision.)